# getting difference in years between two column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as follows. The first column is the year, the second column is the type of pavement treatment, the third column is the score of the pavement. I need to create a third column called 'year diff' by subtracting the year of the last treatment from the year of the current score. For example, year 2014 need to subtract 2013, since treatment 9 is done in 2013, and the result which is 1 need to be recorded in col['year diff'] in the corresponding cell. And year 2022 need to subtract 2020 since treatment 10 is done in 2020.

[image]

Thanks a lot everyone for your help.

Sincerely

Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC , you could use:

```
df['identifier']=(df['year'].diff().eq(1)&df['treatment'].notnull()).cumsum()
df['year diff ']=df.groupby('identifier')['identifier'].apply\
(lambda x: pd.Series(np.where(x!=0,pd.Series(pd.factorize(x)[0]+1).cumsum().shift(),np.nan))).values
print(df)
```

Or if you need to consider the difference of scores based on the value in treatment:

```
df['identifier']=(df['year'].diff().eq(1) &df['treatment'].notnull()).cumsum()
df['year diff']=df.groupby('identifier')['score']\
.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(np.where(x!=0,x.diff().expanding().sum(),np.nan))).reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[df['identifier']==0,'year diff']=np.nan
print(df)

    year  treatment  score  identifier  year diff 
0   2010        NaN      1           0         NaN
1   2011        NaN      2           0         NaN
2   2012        NaN      3           0         NaN
3   2013        9.0      4           1         NaN
4   2014        NaN      5           1         1.0
5   2015        NaN      6           1         2.0
6   2016        NaN      7           1         3.0
7   2017        NaN      8           1         4.0
8   2018        NaN      9           1         5.0
9   2019        NaN     10           1         6.0
10  2020       10.0     11           2         NaN
11  2021        NaN     12           2         1.0
12  2022        NaN     13           2         2.0
13  2023        NaN     14           2         3.0
14  2024        NaN     15           2         4.0
15  2025       12.0     16           3         NaN
16  2026        NaN     17           3         1.0
17  2027        NaN     18           3         2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#check not missing values
m = df['treatment'].notnull()
#create groups starting not missing values
s = m.cumsum()
#add missing values for first group and for not missing values
mask = (s == 0) | m

#subtract score with first score per group 
out =  df['score'] - df['score'].groupby(s).transform('first')
#add missing values
df['year diff'] = np.where(mask, np.nan, out)
print (df)
    year  treatment  score  year diff
0   2010        NaN      1        NaN
1   2011        NaN      2        NaN
2   2012        NaN      3        NaN
3   2013        9.0      4        NaN
4   2014        NaN      5        1.0
5   2015        NaN      6        2.0
6   2016        NaN      7        3.0
7   2017        NaN      8        4.0
8   2018        NaN      9        5.0
9   2019        NaN     10        6.0
10  2020       10.0     11        NaN
11  2021        NaN     12        1.0
12  2022        NaN     13        2.0
13  2023        NaN     14        3.0
14  2024        NaN     15        4.0
15  2025       12.0     16        NaN
16  2026        NaN     17        1.0
17  2027        NaN     18        2.0
```

Comment: i think the score diff is also required, may not be 1 always. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - hmmm, so I understand there are subtract years, or not?

Comment: think the logic is , if year diff = 1, check the last value in treatment and get diff in scores in new column..

Comment: @jezrael  thank you a lot. no subtraction between scores is needed. I only need to know how many years have passed since the last treatment for each score

Comment: @yihaoren - OK, so solution will be changed

Comment: @yihaoren - So need change `out =  df['year'] - df['year'].groupby(s).transform('first')` to `out =  df['score'] - df['score'].groupby(s).transform('first')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do by using a `for` loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata) 
mylist = df.index[df['treatment'] != ''].tolist()
```

And now we subtract the `year` values

```
re_list= []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if index > min(mylist):
        m = [i for i in mylist if i <= index]
        re_list.append(df.iloc[index]['year'] - df.iloc[max(m)]['year'])
else:
    re_list.append(0)

df['Result'] = re_list
```